# How to print a star pattern?

Tags: javascript

I want to print the following star pattern using JavaScript:

```
***** 
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

And I am trying this code, where I am getting off a triangle:

```js
for (i = 3; i >= 1; i--) {
  /* Printing spaces */
  for (j = 0; j <= 3 - i; j++) {
    document.write("&nbsp");
  }
  /* Printing stars */
  k = 0;
  while (k != (2 * i - 1)) {
    document.write("*");
    k++;
  }

  document.write("<br/>")
}
```

Comment: its work properly.so what us the problem

Comment: You have a `for` loop that runs three times, writing a single line each time. Why would you expect it to write more than that, when you explicitly code it to only write the first three??

Comment: but its prints the off triangle but i want full

Comment: Hey OP, look, I think you should NOT ask for a solution. This is exactly the type of beginner problem that you should solve YOURSELF, unless you don't care about learning anything. It's just too simple and by its nature too close to the very basics of understanding how to do anything at all through an algorithm. I suggest you remove your question and figure this out for yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

after `i==1` create new pattern inside it

```js
for (i = 3; i >= 1; i--) {
  /* Printing spaces */
  for (j = 0; j <= 3 - i; j++) {
    document.write("&nbsp");
  }
  /* Printing stars */
  k = 0;
  while (k != (2 * i - 1)) {
    document.write("*");
    k++;
  }

  document.write("<br/>")
  if (i == 1) {
    for (t = 2; t <= 3; t++) {

      for (j = 0; j <= 3 - t; j++) {
        document.write("&nbsp");
      }
      /* Printing stars */
      k = 0;
      while (k != (2 * t - 1)) {
        document.write("*");
        k++;
      }
      document.write("<br/>")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is WAAYYYYY too much code for this simple problem. Did you notice how you repeat the entire first section?

Comment: No - for OP it's "good" if he solves this himself! See my comment under the question. Giving him a convoluted oversized "hey it works is all I care" solution is not "good" for OP. At the very least provide a reasonably good solution, not a code monster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

In this we use outer loop and inner loop.

```js
  var i, j;
  //outer loop
  for(i=1; i <= 5; i++)
   {
   //inner loop
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
   {
     document.write('*');
    }
     document.write('<br/>');
   }
```

Iteration:-

```
i     j(Repeat)
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const n = 5
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var star = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
        star += ' ';
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        star += '* ';
    }
    console.log(star);
}
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var star = '';
    for (var b = 0; b < i; b++) {
        star += ' ';
    }
    for (var a = 0; a < n - i; a++) {
        star += '* ';
    }
    console.log(star);
}
```